# Приём сообщений от пользователей телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Не знаю, как реализовать приём сообщений в телеграм боте. Задача такая, что после определённой команды нужно, чтобы пользователь оставил отзыв и, чтобы у меня была возможность прочесть его. Вот и не знаю, как сделать.

Comment: Берёте любой существующий Telegram-модуль для питона, читаете его документацию и реализовываете

Comment: Не нашёл ничего, что помогло бы реализовать, поэтому я здесь

Comment: Очень странно что не нашли, приём сообщений — это почти самое первое, что описывается в документации абсолютно любой Telegram-библиотеки